# javascript in css not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying a Vertical header using JavaScript and css and html , but the header height is not getting dynamically adjusting , i think i did some thing wrong in calling JSS

Code :

```
 <style>
table, tr, td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

th span {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
</style>
<Script>
$(function() {
    var header_height = 0;
    $('table th span').each(function() {
    if ($(this).outerWidth() > header_height) header_height =         
    $(this).outerWidth();
    });

    $('table th').height(header_height);
});
</script>
<html onload="function()">
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
<th><span>DATE</span></th>
<th><span>ACCOUNTNAME</span></th>
      </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <TD class=AltLight align=left height="17" width="10%">2017/10/20</TD>
<TD class=AltLight align=left height="17" width="10%">USA</TD>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Desired Output

DATE ( Vertically Titled ) Account ( vertically Titled
20/10/2017                  USA

Comment: `outerWidth` or `outerHeight`?

Comment: You are using jQuery in your code. jQuery isnt in your html....

Comment: How to add them in HTML code

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: Take care when spelling JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is jQuery library in your program. You can download the file and build path it in your file. Or you can simply put a link for the library in your page. 
The Link is

```
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

also if you want add bootstrap link. Which will make your page more elegant.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
```

**Update :**   You are using jQuery in your script tag. So it need jQuery library to execute that code.  For this, there is two ways,

1. Downloading the jQuery library file and copy it in the war file of your program. Then Link it to your script Like this,

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="(Location_of_folder /filename.js)jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>`

**Adv** : Offline Access

2. Other way is to use the CDN. This is Google CDN

   `<script 
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
   </script>`

**Adv** : Gets Cached in browser. So the next time, browser will use the Cached CDN. Which makes it faster if you are having many pages in your Web-Application.

Comment: But this needs internet access to the site in code , but servers is not having internet to load them

Comment: @J.RAM you can download JQuery and embed it. [JQuery download](https://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: Yes, If you don't have internet function all the time. Only, way is to download the jQuery library. But note that, above method has the advantage Caching in your browser. So the next time you load it, it will be faster.

Comment: Follow this link to downloading.. http://www.way2tutorial.com/jquery/jquery_download.php

Comment: @RajKanna so I can download in c:\ and <script src="c:\script.js>

Comment: No, Find the location of your project file . And go into the war folder in the directory. Then paste this jQuery jar. Now in your code give as <script src="script.js">
Jar file should always be inside your project folder

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<style>
th span {
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    }
</style>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
<th><span>DATE</span></th>
<th><span>ACCOUNTNAME</span></th>
      </tr>
</thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <TD class=AltLight align=left height="17" width="10%">2017/10/20</TD>
                <TD class=AltLight align=left height="17" width="10%">USA</TD>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<Script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var header_height = 0;
    $('table th span').each(function() {
    if ($(this).outerWidth() > header_height) header_height =         
    $(this).outerWidth();
    });

    $('table th').height(header_height);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```